# Can I have non-static struct inside a static vector

Tags: rust

I have a server application and I'd like to keep sockets and other info in a vector. Right now, for convenience, I want to use a global static vector accessible through a Mutex `game_sessions`.

I know keeping global objects isn't really the best idea in Rust but since this is mostly prototype work it would simplify this part a lot.

The error can be found below but it's asking for a lifetime specifier for the `Option<&TcpStream>` property of PlayerSession.

I'm assuming that it's asking for a *`static* lifetime specifier. Now, I understand that the Mutex and the Vec would have static lifetime but I don't see why the elements inside the vector would have to be static.

Is there any way to make this work ? I know there's other ways to do this but I want to know why this specific way isn't working.

```rust
use std::net::{TcpStream};
use std::sync::*;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum SessionState {
    Closed,
    Active
}

pub struct PlayerSession {
    pub state: SessionState,
    pub player_socket: Option<&TcpStream>
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref game_sessions: Mutex<Vec<PlayerSession>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

pub fn create_player_session(client_socket: &TcpStream) {

    let mut x = game_sessions.lock().unwrap();
    x.push(PlayerSession {
        state: SessionState::Closed,
        player_socket: Some(client_socket)
    });
}
```

When building, the error is :

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src\sessions.rs:12:31
   |
12 |     pub player_socket: Option<&TcpStream>
   |                               ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Still learning the language so, forgive the poor quality of the code, working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
pub struct PlayerSession {
    pub state: SessionState,
    pub player_socket: Option<&TcpStream>
}
```

you are telling rust that a `PlayerSession` may contain a reference to a `TcpStream`.

If you want to store a reference to a socket safely in this data structure, you need to specify the lifetime relationship between the socket owner (not shown in your code sample) and the `PlayerSession` structure. Otherwise, the compiler cannot verify that the socket might be dropped leaving a dangling reference.

The fact that the `PlayerSession` structures happen to be stored in a static `Vec` does not alter this.

If you do not actually need shared access to the socket, the simplest solution might be to make the `PlayerSession` own the socket, rather than just reference it.

Comment: I see ! I will try to update my code with this. Thanks, let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok so I tried to adjust the code with the new structure you suggested but I did not manage to grasp the lifetimes I needed to sprinkle in the code. Instead I changed my approach to avoid using static values and opted instead for a vector created at the higher scopes and passed to down to the dependents that needs a reference to it. Your answer is correct though so I will accept it.